# How to check each form value, and check specific checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, foreach

I try to create function which check for each form, that is input of quantity name is > 1.

So I have for each product seperate form (exactly the same form) with checkboxes.
When somebody change input value quantity in multiple form e.x for 3,5,4 and check checkbox in one of form, all checkboxes when quantity is more than 0 should check.
Or when checkboxes are checked in other forms, and somebody change input quantity on next form it should automaticaly checked this checkbox.
So it should checked checkbox automaticaly (if somebody check only one checkbox) for all form with quantity more than 1.

```
$('form.form_product').each(function (index) {
    let quantity = $(this).find('.quantity').val();
    let bring_checkbox = $(this).find('input.do-bringing');
    let all_checkboxes
    console.log(bring_checkbox);

    $(bring_checkbox).change(function () {
        if (quantity == 0) {
            console.log('zero');
            $(bring_checkbox).prop('checked', false);
        } else {
            $(bring_checkbox).prop('checked', true);
            console.log(index + ' ' + quantity);
        }
    });
});

                <form name="form_add_to_cart" method="POST" class="form_product" id="form_add_to_cart-<?php echo $product_id; ?>" action="">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="price-value col-md-2 col-6">
                            <p><?php echo $product_price; ?> zł</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="quantity-input col-md-3 col-6">
                            <div class="quantity">
                                <input class="form-control quantity" type="number"
                                       id="quantity-<?php echo $product_id; ?>" name="quantity"
                                       max="1000" placeholder="0"
                                       value="<?php echo $product_quantity_added ;?>" >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox-input do-bringing col-md-12 col-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="wash-texter col-md-4 col-12">
                                    <p>Proszę o wniesienie</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="wash-price col-md-3 col-12">
                                    <p><?php echo $product_bringing_price; ?> zł</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox-div col-md-2 col-12">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control do-bringing" id="do_bringing-<?php echo $product_id; ?>"
                                           name="do_bringing">
                                </div>
                                <div class="final-bringing-price col-md-3 col-12">
                                    <input class="non-edit-input final-price-bringing-value final-price"
                                           id="final_bringing_price" name="final_bringing_price-<?php echo $product_id; ?>"
                                           value="0"
                                           readonly="readonly">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="add-to-cart-div col-md-6 col-12">
                            <input class="add-to-cart-button btn btn-primary" type="submit"
                                   name="add_to_cart"
                                   id="add_to_cart-<?php echo $product_id; ?>"
                                   value="Dodaj">
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- END ROW FORM GROUP -->
                </form>
```

Comment: You say `"for each product seperate form (exactly the same form) with checkboxes"` which suggests that the form shown is repeated for every product displayed on your page - however ID attributes **MUST** be unique so `id="form_add_to_cart"` invalidates that rule. The same applies to other elements I noted in the form that have ID attributes - such as `final_bringing_price` & `do_bringing`

Comment: Yes, forms are repeated for every product. I'm using php variable to added product id to input id. I edited my html.